# How does one unlink multiple objects?

Tags: modeling

If i have 10 linked (instanced) objects, how do i make 5 of them local (non-instanced)...

The result would be two sets of 5 objects. Each set of 5 would be linked respectively.

I'm coming from 3ds max so my terminology might be off.

Comment: You can unlink one from those 10 and link 4 ones to the unlinked one. No idea what version you use since in 2.8 that probably doesn't have any shortcuts but in a nutshell to unlink use Relations > Make Single User > Object&Data, to link - Make Links menu

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 2.79 you select the objects and hit U this will bring a menu for unlinking objects with options like object, data, animation, materials etc. If you are using 2.8 you can find under the menu "Object" in 3D view[image]